# XXHDPI emulator stopped after emulate for a while

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just want to run with XXHDPI emulator. I created an emulator of XXHDPI(screen size=5.0, resolution 1080/1920, RAM = 1080 MIB). At first, It run my application well but just 3 or 4 minutes later, the emulator was stopped and show this errors. How can I solve this issue? What should I do? I just want to run with XXHDPI emulator peacefully.

```
05-09 00:28:09.623: E/EGL_emulation(1475): rcCreateWindowSurface returned 0       
05-09 00:28:09.623: E/EGL_emulation(1475): tid 1475: eglCreateWindowSurface(631): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
05-09 00:28:09.633: D/AndroidRuntime(1475): Shutting down VM
05-09 00:28:09.633: W/dalvikvm(1475): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a51ba8)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475): Process: com.speedlink, PID: 1475
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475): java.lang.RuntimeException: createWindowSurface failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:1349)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createEglSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:1241)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:1058)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-09 00:28:09.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try genymotion emulators. They are a lot faster.